# Не получается получить объект из localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

У меня есть объект, пусть это будет:

```js
const obj = {test: true};
```

Я его сохраняю в localStorage:

```js
localStorage.setItem("data", obj);
```

И пытаюсь получить значение:

```js
console.log(localStorage.getItem("data"));
```

... но получаю `[object Object]`, почему?

Получаем такой код (в сниппете не работает localStorage):

```js
const obj = {test: true};
localStorage.setItem("data", obj);

console.log(localStorage.getItem("data"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сохранить объект в localStorage, вам для начала нужно его преобразовать в строку с помощью `JSON.stringify(obj)`, а чтобы получить потом объект, нужно строку преобразовать обратно в объект с помощью `JSON.parse(string)` и вот что у нас должно получиться:

```js
const obj = {test: true};
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(obj));

console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")));
```